# stubborn server-based misformatting of viewport for angular app

Tags: angular, server, media-queries, viewport

I have an angular project that looks great when running on localhost. But when the same code get built and uploaded to my server, the viewport gets messed up and it displays a zoomed out version of the page.

One important note: If I view it on a desktop and resize the browser, its looks great on all sizes. But if, instead, I go into the dev tools and inspect it using a mobile sized device, it looks terrible.

It's like some angular based media query is not getting executed or something.

Has anyone seen this or know of a way to force the server to display the page properly?

viewport tag looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

on localhost, image looks like this:

[image]

Exact same code, using same browser, but rendering from the server, looks like this:

[image]

page is here: https://www.betradating.com/

any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by creating an index.html page at my server root which has nothing more than a redirect link in it that points to my sub-folder.

It appears that having the server set up to automatically stealth url the vanity url to a sub-folder messes something up. But deleting the stealth url and instead redirecting the browser to the sub-folder seems to have fixed the problems.